# Codeigniter dropdown doesn't display the selected value from database

Tags: php, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I am new to codeigniter  and created a dropdown with the fields of my database. So, when I select particular field and click the submit button it should display all those values from my database. I am getting confused on how to pass the field value to my controller file and then to my model file. Can we pass the values only as a array to model or view file?

Controller file:

```
class Dropcontroller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

        public function index()
        {
            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->view('dropview');

        }

        public function data_submitted(){
            $this->load->helper('array');
            $data = array(
            'name'=>$this->input->post('details')
            );
            $this->load->model('Dropmodel');
            $this->Dropmodel->select($data);
            $this->load->model('Dropmodel');
            $result = $this->Dropmodel->select($data);
            $data['result'] = $result[0];
            $this->load->view('dropview',$data);
        }

}
```

Model file:

"My database name is USERS and contains three fields NAME, EMAIL, ID.When i select NAME from dropdown all the names in my database should be displayed"

```
class Dropmodel extends CI_Model{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();  //call the model constructor
        }

    function select($data){
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT $data from users');
        if ($query->num_rows()>0) {
            $data = $query->result();
        return $data;
        } else {
        return false;
        }
    }
```

view file:

```
?php echo form_open('Dropcontroller');?>    
<?php echo '<h1>Creating a dropdown and displaying the results from database</h1>';?><br/>
<?php $options = array(
        'name'         => 'Name',
        'email'           => 'Email',
        'id'         => 'Id',

);

echo form_dropdown('details',$options);?><br/></br>
<?php echo form_submit(array('id'=>'submit','value'=>'submit'));?><br>



<?php echo form_close();?>
<?php if(isset($result)){
    foreach($result as $item){
        print_r($item);
    }
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not passing correct action in your form. You are just using controller name that will not work.

you need to

`<?php echo form_open('Dropcontroller/data_submitted');?>`.

if you are submitting data to `data_submitted`.

Let me know if you have any confusion.

Comment: It worked azam. but i don't know how to pass the select field value in to the query of my model page. I am storing it in array called data but when i include this in my query it displays data error. Please loot at my model page code above and suggest me a solution